# PHP object creation endless loop

Tags: php, oop, infinite-loop

Here's where I have enough knowledge to be dangerous.

I'm working on a web app which has different types of interrelated classes. For example, there is an "Item" class and a "User" class. The "Item" class has a property called "Owner" which refers to a "User" object. Likewise, the "User" class has a property called "Items_array" which is an array that holds (you guessed it) "Item" objects.

My understanding is that objects were automatically returned as a reference, so I have functions for fetch_item, fetch_user, etc. These keep track of a master array of objects, returning the correct one if it already exists and creating a new one if it does not exist. Below is the code to get a user, for example.

```
public function get_user ($userID) {
    if (!isset ($this->users_arr[$userID]))
        $this->users_arr[$userID] = new User($userID);
    return $this->users_arr[$userID];
}
```

I've had properties in my Items class storing User objects with no problem. This morning I added some properties to my User class that store Item objects and now I keep getting 'Unable to open database connection' errors. I've isolated this to the creation of the Item objects - when I comment that out everything works fine. I'm fairly sure I've created some kind of infinite loop where rather than using references, Items are creating Users, which are in turn trying to recreate the Items.

Does this make sense? Anyone run into something like this before or have any thoughts on how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Please post more code, such as the parts that call `get_user()`

Comment: Do you utilize the `__construct()` method? If not, creating new objects cannot ever end up in loop by itself as properties can only be set by scalars in definition.

Comment: what you describe would probably result in some kind of "out of memory" error, rather than a database connection error.  are you sure the database server is running?

Comment: Please show us what you added to properties of user object.

Comment: Get yourself a remote debugger and step through. That way you will find out quickly what's going on.

Comment: Thanks folks. After some debugging I realized there is a logic problem in my get function. If you get stuck in a self referental loop (User 1  owns Item A. User 1 creates Item A, which creates User 1, which creates Item A, etc) the object never finishes it's __construct and gets set to the holder array. therefore every time it tries again to see if the object exists.. it doesn't yet!. Adding a line to set $this->users_arr[$userID] = "somestring" BEFORE creating the object fixed it. Thanks for everyone's help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason I can think of to get "Unable to open database connection" error because of addition of some code is that you open too many of them. MySQL, for example, has a limit of 30 connections per user (that would be you). Normally you shouldn't have more than one connection per script and if you don't store your connection handle globally you can have made an error exactly there.

Comment: My db connection factory used the same logic as above, but it turned out a type was keeping it from returning the existing connection! This combined with the "endless loop" problem (also solved) was causing the db connection error. Before I introduced the looping problem I never maxed out the number of connections.